# Three dots below block element

Tags: html, css

I wanted to design something as like below image, but not sure how to do!

Title with three dots

[image]

So I wanted to display only 3 dots on center below my title. But when I try with `dotted` `border-bottom` it takes entire `<h1>` tag.

```css
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 10px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Title</h1>
```

Comment: It has to be said.  The HTML entity `&hellip;` generates the glyph called a horizontal ellipsis.  This is what typographers use  …  to represent three dots ( when they mean something is omitted ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something as like below snippet. Use spans to create dots and align them center.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: red;
}

.three-dots {
  text-align: center;
}

.three-dots span {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Title</h1>
<div class="three-dots">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

**Update:** Yes of course, i accept that this is not the perfect solution. But same time am sure this will be one of the best solution where you can **customize each dots with different color and size** in easy way as below snippet. Otherwise i would agree [Manish Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46907903/three-dots-below-block-element/46908015#46908015) answer is the best one.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: red;
}

.three-dots {
  text-align: center;
}

.three-dots span {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

span.first {
  background-color: green;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

span.third {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Title</h1>
<div class="three-dots">
  <span class="first"></span>
  <span class="second"></span>
  <span class="third"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Each element that you add consumes browser's memory. You have used one `div` and three `span` elements. While this can be achieved with only one `div` element. See @Manish's answer which is the best so far.

Comment: Maybe more important: You have to add those divs and spans below every `h1` heading on the site, and if you ever want to change the style, you have to replace them, or change the number of spans. Kind of defeats the purpose of using CSS in the first place.

Comment: @MohammadUsman: three extra spans are completely unlikely to make any difference in the memory consumption, and even if you have thousands of them, well I'd say you have bigger issues in your design. However tobias_k gave the real reason why this answer is not a good one.

Comment: I don't know anyone writing vanilla html these days.  Extracting <h1> followed by "three-dots" into a reference'able component is a perfectly reasonable solution if not for the fact that a pure-css solution is the semantically correct one.

Comment: @SébastienDeprez Idea is the same but expressed in 2 different ways. My point was to use only signle element whether it is `h1` or `div` (not both). If you will have thoughts while designing a page that adding 2 or 3 extra elements won't make any difference, you will end up with a page that will have much more extra elements. May be not very obvious but its bad practice in my opinion.

Answer (score 54):

Used `::after` pseudo element for that

```css
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  line-height: 30px;
}
h1::after{
  content:"...";
  font-size: 50px;
  color: gold;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Title</h1>
```

Comment: This won't work as soon as you adopt the same font-family that the question's author used. Arial uses squared dots. That is why in my example i switched the font to another font-family.

Comment: You could try with `&#8226;` (•,  `&#9679;`:  "●" or `&#11044;`: "⬤"), instead of playing with font size!

Answer (score 31):

One pseudo-element and a multiple drop shadows. (drop or box)

**Note:** with this method you can control the color of **each dot**.

**Drop Shadow**

```css
  h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

h1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: .25em;
  height: .25em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orange;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -.5em;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  filter: drop-shadow(.5em 0px 0px blue) 
          drop-shadow(-.5em 0px 0px green);
}
```

```html
<h1>My Title</h1>
```

**Box Shadow** (thanks to Ilmari Karonen)

```css
  h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}

h1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: .25em;
  height: .25em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orange;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: -.5em;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  box-shadow: .5em 0px 0px blue, 
              -.5em 0px 0px green;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Title</h1>
```

Comment: Now the one with perfectly right process.. +1 from me :)

Comment: For me (Chromium 61 on Ubuntu Linux) the middle orange dot has a funny greenish ring around it. Changing the background color from orange to white makes it really obvious. I don't know why it's there, but it seems like the color of the ring matches the color of the last drop shadow.

Comment: Ps. It seems that replacing the `filter` property with the (supposedly) equivalent `box-shadow: .5em 0px 0px blue, -.5em 0px 0px green` gets rid of the weird ring around the middle dot.

Comment: This is the most interesting solution of all.

Comment: a bit late, but i agree this one is the best solution as it can control each dots separately and we can also add **more** dots if needed easily.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo element.

```css
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}
h1:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-bottom: 10px dotted red
}
```

```html
<h1>My title</h1>
```

Comment: These don't look much like circles…

Comment: Do you mean **the** circles, as those on the screen provided in the question? Or not like circles at all?

Comment: The question asks for "dots", and shows a picture of 3 round things underneath the text. Your example produces three squares underneath the text.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that `border-style: dotted` produces squares in any browser. Which one do you use?

Comment: I believe Firefox uses square dots.

Comment: I was looking at it in Safari on macOS. Firefox on Linux seems to use round dots. I did not realize this was paltform-dependent, either.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out anyway. I use Chrome on Linux and it's round; here: https://medium.com/@luclemo/creating-true-dotted-borders-with-css-233f296d8145 is nice workaround, if ever necessary.

Comment: Don't just calculate the dimension, you're begging for problems. For me (Firefox 56, Linux, default fonts) it displays just two dots. Round, though :-)

Answer (score 5):

## Same [manish-patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6284661/manish-patel)'s answer, but

## ●   ●   ●

As I prefer to

- not force font size
- use adaptive `em` size unit instead of fixed `pt` or `px`.
- **K**eep **I**t **S**hort and **S**imple

---

This will use UTF-8, one of *black circle*:

> ```
> &#10625;   U+2981    Z NOTATION SPOT          ⦁
> &#8226;    U+2022    BULLET                   •
> &#9679;    U+25CF    BLACK CIRCLE             ●
> &#9899;    U+26AB    MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE      ⚫
> &#11044;   U+2B24    BLACK LARGE CIRCLE       ⬤
> ```

Fist, using `BLACK LARGE CIRCLE: ⬤`

```css
h1{
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
h1::after{
  content:"⬤ ⬤ ⬤";
  color: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Title</h1>
```

Or with `BLACK CIRCLE: ●`

```css
h1{ text-align: center; line-height: 1.3em ;}
h1::after{ content:"● ● ●"; color: blue; display: block ;}
```

```html
<h1>My Title</h1>
```

### With a little enhancement: adding *blurred border* to dots

Mixing both `BLACK CIRCLE: ●` and `BLACK LARGE CIRCLE: ⬤` ;)

```css
h1        { text-align: center; line-height: 1.3em; }
h1::after { content:"●⬤● ●⬤● ●⬤●"; color: blue; display: block;
            text-shadow: 0em 0em .2em #008; }
```

```html
<h1>My Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the **::after** pseudo-selector and define a **line-height** for your h1 element to vertically space the dots from the title. Use **Georgia** as web font for the dots as **Arial** has squared dots.

Remember you can use both syntax but is preferably use the `::after`to distinguish
pseudo-classes from pseudo-elements.

```
/* CSS3 syntax */
::after

/* CSS2 syntax */
:after
```

> CSS3 introduced the ::after notation (with two colons) to distinguish
>   pseudo-classes from pseudo-elements. Browsers also accept :after,
>   introduced in CSS2. Caveats

```css
h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
  line-height: 20px;
}

h1::after {
   content: '...';
   display: block;
   font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
   font-size: 100px;
   color: #FEC832;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Heading</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with flexbox:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: black;
  line-height: 24px;
}
h1::after {
    content: "...";
    font-size: 72px;
    color: gold;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    letter-spacing: 5px
}
```

```html
<h1>
  My Heading
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution where you can rely on multiple `radial-gradient` to create each circle. Then you can easily control the **number** of circles, their **position**, **colors**, and **size**.

### 3 Circles as needed

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  padding-bottom:0.3em;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side, blue   98%,transparent 100%) calc(50% - 25px) 100%, 
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side, orange 98%,transparent 100%) 50%              100%,
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side, green  98%,transparent 100%) calc(50% + 25px) 100%;
  background-size:25px 0.3em;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Title</h1>
```

### 5 Circles

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  padding-bottom:0.3em;
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side, purple 97%,transparent 100%) calc(50% - 50px) 100%, 
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side, blue   97%,transparent 100%) calc(50% - 25px) 100%, 
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side, orange 97%,transparent 100%) 50%              100%,
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side, green  97%,transparent 100%) calc(50% + 25px) 100%,
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side, red    97%,transparent 100%) calc(50% + 50px) 100%;
  background-size:25px 0.3em;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Title</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Solution with radial-gradient css property.

```css
   .horizontal-dots {
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-image: radial-gradient(circle, black, black 3px, transparent 4px, transparent);
        background-size: 10px 25px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-dots">
</div>
```