# SVG border-image perfect on Chrome, stretch on Firefox

Tags: css, svg

My problem is this :

I have a SVG image on a border-image CSS. 
It render like I want on Chrome, but it's stretched on Firefox.

I have to modify width and height value, inside the SVG, to "fix" it, but it show a lot of dots, when I want just 3.

More explicite with this : https://codepen.io/benCat/pen/EeJmwL

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

hr {
    position: relative;
    width: 45em;
    border-width: 0 0 1em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 2 1" width="50" height="4" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="meet"><circle fill="rgba(136, 165, 122, 0.4)" cx="1" cy="0.5" r="0.5"/></svg>') 0 0 100% repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Normaly, 3 perfect dots with lot of space between</h1>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Can I solve it by this way ?

Am I wrong to use border-image to make a simple dot ?

**EDIT** : I want to make dots with SVG for some reasons, no matter the way, but only in SVG :)

Thank you !

Comment: Yes using SVG and border image for simple dot is too much .. check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069041/8620333

Comment: Thank you Temani, but I want to use SVG, border-image or <svg> tag, I don't care, but I want it in SVG for some reasons :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that `preserveAspectRatio` doesn't work as intended in Firefox ( at least not in data uris). If you need it working you need to keep the proportions: If you want `viewBox='0 0 2 1'` and  `width='50'` you need `height='25'` not height='4'. Of coarse this may not be what you need, but you get the gist.
Also: in CSS is better to use [encoded SVG](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris)

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

hr {
    position: relative;
    width: 45em;
    border-width: 0 0 1em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 2 1' width='50' height='25' xml:space='preserve' preserveAspectRatio='meet'%3E%3Ccircle fill='rgba(136, 165, 122, 0.4)' cx='1' cy='0.5' r='0.5'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") 0 0 100% repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Normaly, MANY perfect dots with SOME space between</h1>
  <hr>
</div>
```

UPDATE:
In order to get only 3 points you need to change the SVG for example like this.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

hr {
    position: relative;
    width: 45em;
    border-width: 0 0 1em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' viewBox='-7 0 16 1' width='400' height='25' xml:space='preserve' preserveAspectRatio='meet'%3E%3Ccircle fill='rgba(136, 165, 122, 0.4)' cx='1' cy='0.5' r='0.5'/%3E%3C/svg%3E") 0 0 100% repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Normaly, 3 perfect dots with lot of space between</h1>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello enxaneta ! That's exactly what I want, I've tried to change the height by 25 to respect the ratio, but I think I did not understand how to use viewbox... Thank you very much, now I know how to use it in the futur ! Thanks again :)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe do it as background?

```
hr {
    position: relative;
    width: 45em;
    height: 1em;
    border: none;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 2 1" width="50" height="4" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="meet"><circle fill="rgba(136, 165, 122, 0.4)" cx="1" cy="0.5" r="0.5"/></svg>') 0 0 100% repeat;
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it just show a long filled line, it's just a full background without radius. And background-image do not accept this syntax after url().. Thanks anyway ! :)